# How to convert pushed regular merge into squash-merge in git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

I have accidentally merged my 20 commits using `regular commit` from `feature branch` to the `main` branch. Is there any way to revert it and make it as `squash and merge`? The purpose is to make the `main` branch clean. It should only have one commit for my 20 commits in the `feature branch`.

Comment: You pushed `main` already? If yes, do you have permission to *force* push `main`? If still yes, does your team have a policy about when you are allowed to force push `main` and how to notify others if you did? (How many people are using the repo and could be affected by it?)

Comment: Yes, I have pushed to base branch. It is our own repo. The latest commits are just my merged commits. Everyone in the group notice that, so we would like to figure out this first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a disclaimer. A standard rule of thumb in Git is:

> Don't force push shared branches, because it can mess up other people.

But of course a rule of thumb can have exceptions if you are willing to deal with the consequences, and in your case it sounds like you are:

> Everyone in the group notice that, so we would like to figure out this first.

So the fix for this is fairly straight forward:

```
# tell everyone you are going to rewrite the main branch
git checkout main
git pull main
# look at main and make sure other people didn't add more commits after yours
git reset --hard <last-good-commit-id-before-your-feature-branch>
git merge feature-branch --squash
# at this point a single squashed commit is staged and ready to be committed
git commit -m "Merge and squash feature branch"
# now replace the remote main branch with your copy
git push --force-with-lease
# now tell everyone it is fixed and they can resume work
```

**Note:** You asked about "revert", but in Git the term "revert" means to create a new commit which undoes a previous existing commit. That will leave the history intact and change functionality. You actually want the opposite because you want to leave the functionality intact and change the history. To change history you need to "rewrite" commits, which in this case consists of resetting backwards to remove commits, and recreating a new commit.

**Side Note**: you might want to consider setting up branch policies on `main` and using Pull Requests for merges into `main`. Then (let's hope) someone reviewing your code would see a lot of commits in your PR and could tell you to squash them first. Or, you could set up a squash merge policy so that it happens automatically when the PR is completed.

Comment: Just as a point of info, you can configure your repo in GitHub so that _only_ Squash And Merge is possible.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I am asking.